# .net core angular spa templates with IdentityServer

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, spa-template

I'm using this template: [SPA Template](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/ProjectTemplates/Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates/content/Angular-CSharp)
And I want to understand how I can change layout of user registration and user login ?

Thanks and Regards,
Danijel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, It took me 2 days to find out how!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli

In short -  you need to run something like :

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --useDefaultUI
```

That will generate all .cshtml files. From that you could unleash your html&css skills :)

Comment: Actually for already exist project need to follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-a-razor-project-with-authorization
Anyway your right for generation.

Comment: The next challenge I trying to solve is keeping JWT token alive while user is using the session